# how to store xtype value as String Array CQ5 / AEM

Tags: extjs, aem

I have dialog with set of xtypes defined.
One of xtype is "selection" with type "select".
Now each option has a value type "String[]" , but when I add the component to a page and look at the option selected content.

**It is stored as "String" rather than "String[]".**

Could anyone tell me how to make/force a xtype store its values in a "String[]" , rather than "String".

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the Sling parameters to manipulate the content creation through the `SlingPostServlet`. Read more: [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#typehint)

In reality, just add a hidden field to your dialog that will pass the `@TypeHint` parameter with the expected property type. If your xtype saves data to e.g. `cities` property you can add the following:

```
<citiesTypeHint
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="cities@TypeHint"
    value="String[]"
    xtype="hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding xtype in dialog.xml, add it as :

```
property=value
```

This will create a `property` of `String` type with value as `value`.

If you want an array put the value in `[]`, as :

```
property="[value1,value2,value3,...]"
```

This will create a `property` of `String[]` type with value as `value`. If you want to add more, separate then with  coma.

If you want to define dataType, as :

```
property="{dataType}value"
```

This will create a `property` of `dataType` type with value as `value`. Where dataType may be any DataType like `Boolean, Date, Long, etc`

If you are adding Property with crx/de then click on `add multi` button in the bottom right corner.

Hope this Helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

Mateusz Chromiński variant almost worked for me, except that `value="String[]"` results in emprty property, so I have used `defaultValue="String[]"` and it worked just perfect.

```
<targetGroupsTypeHint
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  name="./targetGroups@TypeHint"
  defaultValue="String[]"
  xtype="hidden"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Enter the following in the dialog:

```
typeHint="String[]"
```